# Why does uint 0 - 20 not cause an underflow?

Tags: solidity, uint256

I expect this to underflow and become a big number. But calling this method I get a:

> MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted

```
function over() public pure returns (uint) {
    uint a = 0;
    return a - 20;
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because since [solidity 0.8.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/080-breaking-changes.html) the overflow / underflow are automatically checked :

"Arithmetic operations revert on underflow and overflow. You can use unchecked { ... } to use the previous wrapping behaviour.
Checks for overflow are very common, so we made them the default to increase readability of code, even if it comes at a slight increase of gas costs.
"

So, `a - 20` does cause an underflow that is detected and triggers a revert.

As per the documentation, this would not revert and allow you to observe the huge value returned : `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639916`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
  function under() public pure returns (uint) {
        uint a = 0;
        unchecked {
            return a - 20;
        }
    }
}
```